# How to create boundary (outline) polygon from raster grid (GeoTIFF floating point grid)

Tags: qgis, gdal

I would like to create a vector boundary polygon from a raster(for instance GeoTIFF floating point grid) in a smooth way.

Anyone have a clue about how to use QGIS and/or GDAL?
Input: GeoTIFF floating point grid 10m resolution.

Output: Boundary polygon (vector)     (For now only around the edges of the raster.Later on I would like to create vector polygons of the holes within the raster too. )

[image: Raster as input]

[image: Output as vector boundary polygon]

Comment: you could use a concave hull tool.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it by this way:

1. Use the raster calculator with this expression `"raster@band" != nodata_value` (replace: 'raster' with the name of your raster layer, 'band' with the band number that you are working with and nodata_value with the no-data value of your raster)
2. Polygonize the calculation done in the first step.

What does this expression (`"raster@band" != nodata_value`)? Basically it takes every pixel that has data an replace it with the value one.

Comment: I think you meant "polygonize", not "rasterize" as the second step. And if the aim is a boundary as a linestring then the third step would be to convert the polygon geometry into linestring.